# Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon on working on inner pages

Tags: ribbon

I have a publishing portal site set up with all relevant features enabled. The ribbon is completely greyed out and does not allow me access to any editing, publishing or browsing features. However, on the homepage, i have access to all these features. I am using a custom master page and home page template. There are no javascript errors on any of the pages. I have tried removing all the custom javascript on the page, but it has no effect.